# Quitar el .php de las paginas web en la url

Tags: .htaccess, url

Tengo un .htaccess en la raiz de la carpeta de mi web con el siguiente contenido:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Con esto intento es que a la hora de acceder a mi sitio web, me aparezca por ejemplo,

> www.nombredeldominio.com/inicio

y no

> www.nombredeldominio.com/inicio.php

Aclarar que tengo mi sitio web en un hosting que corre en linux.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la ultima RewriteRule por: `RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php`

Comment: @Ferni lo acabo de probar y me sigue saliendo la extensión .php

Comment: ¿Cual es el nombre del hosting en el que tienes tu web?

Comment: Es un hosting que hay en la escuela, en el cual entro por cPanel

Comment: Prueba poniendo la 3ª línea así: **`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`**

Comment: @A.Cedano Sigue sin funcionar, no entiendo porque

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]` O bien, intenta a implementar [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084526/5587982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al código que muestras sólo le falta un carácter.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Revisa el segundo **RewriteCond** y agrega diagonal invertida entre **{REQUEST_FILENAME}** y **.php -f**